# Infinitude of primes deduced from $\zeta(2) - 1 < 1$, is this proof known?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have observed that the infinitude of primes can be obtained with an elementary argument that I couldn't find in the literature (nor referred online) so I wonder if anyone is familiar with this approach. The idea is to observe that if there were only finitely many primes, then the number of square-free positive integers should also be finite. Starting from here, you can get a contradiction (with the assumption that the number of primes is finite) just by estimating the density of the set of square-free numbers as a subset of the (infinite) set of positive integers. For this, just consider the complementary set of non-square-free numbers and observe that, since each such number is divisible by $p^2$ for some prime $p$, its density can be bounded by $1/4 + 1/9 + 1/25 + ....$, the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of the primes.
This sum is itself bounded by $\zeta(2) - 1$ (here $\zeta$ stands for Riemann's zeta function, whose value at $2$ is just the sum of the reciprocals of the squares of all positive integers), and we can easily bound $\zeta(2) - 1$, using for example the standard trick from first year calculus to bound a decreasing sequence by an integral (in this case the integral between $2$ and $\infty$ of the function $1/(x-1)^2$), to deduce that it is smaller than $1$.
This implies that the set of square-free numbers has positive density (i.e., they constitute a positive proportion of the set of all positive integers), thus in particular there are infinitely many such numbers. This implies that there are infinitely many primes.

As a teacher, I should mention that this proof comes from the wrong observation of a student claiming that it was "obvious" that the number of primes is infinite since there are infinitely many positive integers all of them factoring into primes. When I heard this student's argument I realized that he was simply forgetting that when you factor a number there can be repeated prime factors. This is of course a major mistake, but this made me observe that since square-free numbers are not that rare it should be possible to get a proof of the infinitude of primes starting from this erroneous remark!

Comment: Not sure whether a proof works using this approach. Of course , there are many simple proofs of the claim that there are infinite many primes. The most elegant one I am aware of uses the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: In fact, about $61$% of the positive integers are squarefree (to be exact : The fraction is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$) , in the sense that the fraction tends to this value if we check the positive integers from $1$ to $N$ and let $N$ tend to $\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

If $S_j$ are some sets of integers and $S=\bigcup_j S_j$ then it doesn't imply that the densities satisfy $d(S)\le \sum_{j\ge 1} d(S_j)$ (try $S=\Bbb{N},S_j=\{j\}$).

So you may need something like this, making the argument *less elementary*:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac1N\sum_{n\le N} |\mu(n)| \ge 
\lim_{N\to \infty}  \frac1N(N-\sum_{k\ge 2,m\ge 1,k^2 m\le N}1 )= 
\lim_{N\to \infty}  1-\frac1N\sum_{2\le k\le N} \lfloor N/k^2 \rfloor$$
$$ \ge \lim_{N\to \infty}  1-\sum_{2\le k\le N} 1/k^2 = 2-\zeta(2)> 0$$
Showing that there are infinitely many square-free numbers and hence infinitely many primes.

Comment: Thanks! I see your point, one needs to be more careful about estimating densities then.

Comment: One has to work first on an interval [1 ,N] to bound the size of the set of non-square-free elements there, and then let N go to infinity at the end.